# Adding element with index to an array in PostgreSQL

Tags: arrays, postgresql

Can I specify an index (using some counter) to an element when adding elements to an array in PostgreSQL?

For example, I have this code from Oracle PL/SQL and I want to write it in PostgreSQL:

```
invoice_list.EXTEND;
invoice_list(counter):= cfp_cur.invoice_no; --adding some invoices from a loop to a text array

amount_list.EXTEND;
amount_list(counter) := inv_amount; --adding some amounts to a number array

counter := counter + 1; --increasing counter
```

Comment: Simply use `||` to append an element to an array: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-array.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PostgreSQL does not have an `EXTEND` method like Oracle does. PostgreSQL, however, can extend 1-dimensional arrays automatically by assigning array elements beyond the end of the current array length.

In your example, this becomes very simply:

```
CREATE FUNCTION some_function () RETURNS something AS $$
DECLARE 
  invoice_list   text[];
  amount_list    float8[];
BEGIN
  -- Do something
  ...

  FOR counter IN 1 ... 10 LOOP
    -- get current values for cfp_cur.invoice_no and inv_amount
    invoice_list[counter] := cfp_cur.invoice_no;
    amount_list[counter] := inv_amount;
  END LOOP;

  -- Do something with the arrays
  ...
  RETURN;
END;
```

Comment: You can also use `||` to concatenate an element to the end of an array `invoice_list := invoice_list || cfp_cur.invoice_no` http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-array.html

Comment: Thx @Patrick , this helps. And what is the easiest way to display these array just to check them?

Comment: Quick-and-dirty: `SELECT my_array::text`. Not so q-n-d: `array_to_string(my_array, ',')`